# Get page id of current page from template

Tags: page-template

I am trying to get page id from my `template-contact.php` like this :

```
global $post;
echo $post->ID;
```

It's showing 85 but page id is 96, I want to get id because I want to fetch meta of current page.

Here is my template code.

```
<?php /* Template Name: Contact Page */ ?>

<?php get_header() ?>
<?php 

global $post;
echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'contact_page', true);


?>
<?php get_footer() ?>
```

Please help

Comment: That code is correct (although I'd use `get_the_ID()` to do the same). Where in your template are you loading it exactly? Are you sure you're calling that from within [the loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)?

Comment: I have edited the question and added my template code, how to get meta information for the page, 
in $post->ID i am getting a post's id instead of current page's id

Comment: got it, I just had to write `the_post()` before `global $post`.

Comment: I want to point out that $wp_query->post->ID and get_the_ID() could be cached depending on a verity of themes, theme builder systems, plugins and other settings. the post below using get_queried_object_id works as the most reliable method outside the loop from an "absolute" perspective. I have ran into a problem "trusting" get_the_ID() in many of these modern themes/builder systems out there because they pass the ID through a series of builder page/templates that obfuscates the "REAL" ID of the page you think you are on depending on what you are trying to do in-template

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the ID of the page being queried from outside the loop or before the global post object has been set, use `get_queried_object_id()`.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Contact Page 
 */

get_header();
?>

<?php
$page_id = get_queried_object_id();
echo get_post_meta( $page_id, 'contact_page', true);
?>

<?php get_footer() ?>
```

Comment: Yours is the correct answer. I want to point out that $wp_query->post->ID and get_the_ID() could be cached depending on a verity of plugins or settings. I agree get_queried_object_id works.